# CesiumJS: bad imagery quality (resolution) in very close views

Tags: imagery, resolution, cesium

My TMS-Layer displayed in my Cesium-App is very unsharp rendered in a close view.
When I zoom out the resolution is perfect.
The resolution in the PNG tiles (Zoom-Level 21) is much higher than displayed in Cesium.

Anyone an idea how to set up a higher possible image resolution in cesium in closer views like in my image?

[image: unsharp imagery rendering from tms source]

Comment: How is your layer configured?

Comment: "imageryLayers": [
  {
      "layerType": "tms",
      "pfad": "/assets/wendelmatte/layer_gp",
      "anzeigename": "hoch",
   "transparenz": 1,
      "legendeBild": "wendelmatte/images/gp_legende.PNG"
    }